# Symfony2 slow login with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Im launching an app in Symfony while using FOSUserBundle to handle the site login. On my Local machine the login works fine taking around 3 seconds. Yet on production it takes around 13-15 seconds. Looking in dev tools, after entering the login form the site gets held up "waiting" on login_check. Is there a reason why login_check has such a long wait on production?

Comment: can you give me your live/production url ?

Comment: Is your prod env database config pointing to localhost or literal? Also do all other queries take so long or just log-in

Comment: @Doug the prod DB points to localhost. All other queries work fine except for account creation which also has a delay similar to the login.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same problem.  login_check took 30+ seconds to "process" before I was successfully logged in.  This only happened in Production.  The reason was that I had recently changed from a shared IP to a dedicated IP.  However, I had forgotten to update my Swiftmailer settings.  I was trying to use invalid mailer values for host, user, and password.  It took 30 seconds for Swiftmailer to timeout.  After changing to the correct values it worked.

Hopefully this will help somebody.